# Remove image tags from inside all anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table header:

```
<table id="time" class="new_table" border="0" cellpadding="2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" rowspan="2" class="sortHead">
                <a href="#" id="unitSort">Unit</a>
            </th>
            <th colspan="2" id="startDateHead" class="sortHead">
                <a href="#" id="startDateSort">Start</a>
            </th>
            <th colspan="2" id="endDateHead" class="sortHead">
                <a href="#" id="endDateSort">End</a>
            </th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="sortHead">
                <a href="#" id="distanceSort">Distance (miles)</a>
            </th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="sortHead">
                <a href="#" id="locationSort">Location</a>
            </th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="sortHead">
                <a href="#" id="driverName">Driver Name</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
```

I am dynamically adding and removing img tags to the a tag when a user clicks a button. How can I remove all img tags within the a tags of this table when they are there?

I have tried:

```
$('#time th a').each(function() { $(this).remove('img'); });
```

An example of the img element that is added to the a tag is as follows:

```
<a href="#" id="driverName">Driver Name<img id="test" src="test.png" width="10"></a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I remove all img tags within the a tags of this table when
>   they are there.

Simply

```
$('#time th a img').remove();
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4n7q3bu5/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt works if you flip the syntax a bit. I can't explain why your version didn't work. [The docs](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) indicate that it should.

```
$('#time th a').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').remove();
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4n7q3bu5/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

i modified your code little bit, i added `.find("img")` then use `.remove()`

```js
$('#time th').each(function () {
                $(this).find("img").remove();                
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table id="time" class="new_table" border="0" cellpadding="2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" rowspan="2" class="sortHead">
                    <a href="#" id="driverName">Driver Name<img id="test" src="arrow.png" width="10" /></a>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" rowspan="2" class="sortHead">
                    <a href="#" id="A1">Driver Mobile<img id="Img1" src="arrow.png" width="10"></a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Hope this will help you.